# How to get JS file to pull data from database

Tags: javascript, django, sqlite, templates, django-models

I am new to Django and am working on a simple project that involves having a form that a user submits and then a dashboard page that gives some nice visual charts summarising the data input by the user. I am using a free template for the dashboard page. It is called black-dashboard by creative tim.

In my HTML template there is the following

```
<canvas id="chartBig1"></canvas>
```

this I believe references information in a JS file about the chart to display

below is a snippet of the JS file that I think the html references

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctxGreen, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipGreen

});



var chart_labels = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
var chart_data = [100, 70, 90, 70, 85, 60, 75, 60, 90, 80, 110, 100];


var ctx = document.getElementById("chartBig1").getContext('2d');
```

The data is static. What is the best way to display these graphs using data that I have saved using models.py . Can I pull the data straight into the JS file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can move the JS snippet to your html template and delete it in the file, then render the data like this:

```
# template.html
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    var myChart = new Chart(ctxGreen, {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipGreen
    });

    var chart_labels = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
    var chart_data = [
      {% for instance in queryset %}
        {{ instance.data_point }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    ];

    var ctx = document.getElementById("chartBig1").getContext('2d');

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: @thebjorn the comma is inside the for loop, so if the queryset is empty the for loop won't run and the comma won't be rendered. Also, a trailing comma in an Array doesn't have a negative effect in javascript, for example ```var data = [1, 2, 3,];```

Comment: @thebjorn if you don't like the trailing comma because of aesthetics, you can do this: ```{% for instance in queryset %}{{ instance.data_point }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}```

Comment: @thebjorn do you have any suggestions of the best way then ? In your opinion

Comment: @Pedro my bad. It used to be a syntax error in IE, but apparently they've fixed it (yay!)

Comment: @MatthewMacfarlane if you dont want the trailing comma just do:
```{% for instance in queryset %}{{ instance.data_point }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}```

Answer (score 0):

you can also store data from your context that you are passing to your template from the backend in a variable that is accessible to the included script. so if you have for instance a context from your view that is

```
context = { 'name': name }
```

in your template inside of script tags you can do

```
<script>var randomJsVariableName = "{{ name }}";</script>
```

and you should be able to access that in the external js file as long as it is included in your template after the script tag with the variable in it i.e.

```
<script>var randomJsVariableName = "{{ name }}";</script>
<script src="externalJsFile.js"></script>
```

also remember that if in your main inheritable template if you have a block for js to use the block tags for your js in the template you are currently working on. also as a side note I'm using `var` here instead of `let` or `const` because this is in an html template and I don't know if you have babel set up in some way and I believe IE or Edge dont like let and const

EDIT:
@thebjorn is correct when saying that this will return a typeof string. you can assign it to a variable without using quotes and just get the original type you are passing, or you can pass the string and parse it in the js

Comment: This would make `randomJsVariableName` always be of type string, regardless of what type `name` has in your context.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of doing this is to create a django template filter that converts a context variable to json (which by design is valid a valid javascript value literal):

```
from django.import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
import json
register = template.Library

@register.filter
def jsonval(val):
    """Output ``val`` as a (json) value suitable for assigning to variables in
       javascript::

           var js_var = {{ python_var|jsonval }};

    """
    return mark_safe(json.dumps(val, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

this needs to be placed in your app's templatetags folder, normally in a file named `myapp_tags.py` (read more about creating custom filters in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/).

In your template you'll need to load your filter before using it:

```
{% load myapp_tags %}
....
var chart_data = {{ chart_data|jsonval }};
....
```

In your view you'll need to make sure that the chart_data context variable is json-serializable -- ie. only contains lists, dicts, strings, numbers, booleans, and None (ie. no Django querysets etc.).
The documentation on json contains information on ways around this limitation, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html -- under "Extending JSONEncoder"; this might require a similar decoding step on the js side: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter although that will make your filter tag a bit more complex:

```
@register.simple_tag
def json_setup():
    return """
    var my_reviver = function (key, val) {
        if (typeof val === 'string' && val.startsWith("@date:")) {
            var dateval = val.slice("@date:".length);
            return new Date(Date.parse(dateval));
        }
        return val;  // else
    };
    """

class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
            return "@date:" + obj.isoformat()   # e.g. "@date:2019-03-15"
        if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
            return float(obj)
        # ..etc..
        # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

@register.filter
def jsonval(val):
    return mark_safe('JSON.parse("%s", my_reviver)' % json.dumps(val, cls=MyEncoder, sort_keys=True))
```

and your template:

```
{% load myapp_tags %}
{% json_setup %}
....
var chart_data = {{ chart_data|jsonval }};
....
```

Comment: You should also add support to Decimal fields

Comment: @Pedro There are very many types you can add support for, both Python supplied and library supplied.  My work in this area can be found in my dkjs library available at github.  Relevant starting points for this question would be: https://github.com/thebjorn/dkjs/blob/master/src/data/datacore/dk-json.js, https://github.com/thebjorn/dkjs/blob/master/src/browser/dk-client.js#L75, and https://github.com/thebjorn/dkjs/blob/master/dkjs/jason.py.  Handling of Decimal values happens at https://github.com/thebjorn/dkjs/blob/master/dkjs/jason.py#L55.

Comment: I mentioned Decimal fields because the script is to graph charts.

Comment: @Pedro I've updated the answer with an if for `decimal.Decimal` (you'll need to `import decimal` too of course).  Remember to upvote any answer that has been helpful to you...